# Bootstrap Inline styling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display a series of elements inline as in the following picture using bootstrap:

[image: Issue Image]

After I add the "form-control" class to the input it moves below the other elements.  I have tried several different combinations and can't come up with the correct set of classes and styling.

The html is below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
        <label class="control-label">
            Unique ID @Model.Ordering:
            <input class="form-control" type="number" required />
        </label>
        <strong>Name:</strong> @Model.Name
        <strong>DOB:</strong> @Model.DateOfBirth
        <strong>Gender: </strong>@Model.Gender
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my updated code which now works correctly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                Unique ID @Model.Ordering:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Name:</strong> @Model.Name
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>DOB:</strong> @Model.DateOfBirth
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Gender: </strong>@Model.Gender
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `<form class="form-inline">` look at the [inline documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

Comment: This snippet is a small snippet of my code.  I don't want the entire form to be inline just the section that is part of this div.  But I will look at the documentation that I overlooked.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help I found out that I needed to as you said add the form-inline class and also wrap my input elements in div elements with the class "form-group"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for bootstrap's [inline form class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). Have you already added `.form-inline` to your `form` tag?